# Displaying table information based off another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables:

```
users:
--------------------
id | name | 
 1 | john |
 2 | bob  |

events
--------------------
id |  name   | location
 1 | concert | moon
 2 | sport   | ukraine

user_events
--------------------
id |  userid | eventid
 1 |   1     |   1 
 2 |   1     |   2 
 3 |   2     |   2
```

I am trying to display which events the user is going to. I want to retrieve and only display the event information, but only the information of events that a certain user is going to.

How would I list the event information from the events John is attending?

So the output would be:

```
johns events
--------------------
concert | moon
sport   | ukraine
```

Really hope I've explained this well enough! If not please say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, an `INNER JOIN` will suffice you need because you only want the event that user will be attending.

```
SELECT  c.name, c.location
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN user_events b
            ON a.ID = b.userID
        INNER JOIN events c
            ON b.eventID = c.ID
WHERE   a.name = 'JOHN'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76c73/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╦══════════╗
║  NAME   ║ LOCATION ║
╠═════════╬══════════╣
║ concert ║ moon     ║
║ sport   ║ ukraine  ║
╚═════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, thank you so much for the time you took to do this. Really appreciate it! I will confirm your answer in 8minutes. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - one last thing. I will later need to give the user the ability to delete events that they're going to. How can I store the user_events.id to reference later if they wish to delete it? Thanks

Comment: for history references, maybe you can add extra column on table `user_events` called `IsDeleted` (*integer*). The default value is zero. When the user wants to delete, you will only update its value to one. And there is a slight changes in your query if you do that. Add a filtering condition `WHERE   a.name = 'JOHN' AND b.IsDeleted = 0` if you only want to show active events that the user will be attending.

Comment: Brilliantly intuitive, thank you very much just made my life a whole lot easier!

Comment: I'm happy to hear your feedback `:)`